# Passing external parameter to .exe on Windows using winexe from Linux

Tags: shell, quoting, wine

I am trying to execute a .exe on Windows from Linux using winexe. This exe requires an external parameter (string) to be fed alongwith. With the following command I have succeeded in initialising the .exe using the below command on Linux command Prompt:

```
/usr/bin/winexe -U domain/user%pwd //COMP123 --interactive=1 "C:\TEST\OS.exe"
```

At the same time I need to pass an external parameter (String with spaces E.g: PUR 000000001000 RIY ) via the command prompt to this .exe for complete execution.

Is this possible, if yes, can somebody help me with the syntax to be followed for this requirement. Many thanks in advance.